# Check if Point on circle is between two other points on circle

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry

I'm looking for a better solution than the 2 algorithms I've currently written (in C) to check if a point on the circumference of a circle is located in the ***short arc*** created ***between*** two other points on the same circle.

For example: p1 = 358 deg, p2 = 1 deg on the circumference, and I need to know if p3 = .5 degrees is located between p1 and p2 (the solution should regard it as such).

**Clarification**: For this use case I only check "betweenness" if p1 != p3 or p2 != p3. In those exceedingly rare cases (floating point numbers) I already have the answer I need.

This problem is complicated by the fact that sometimes retrograde motion means p2 < p1, and also because p1 and p2 can straddle the 0/360 degree boundary.

My real world use case (in case you are interested) is to determine when to continue on and apply an interpolation algorithm for finding exact time of conjunction (occultation) between two bodies in space, one body represented by p1 & p2 at known times, and a different object at p3.

Comment: Have you thought about using the modulo?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "between"?  Two distinct points on a circle divide the circle into two arcs.  Any other point on the circle is in one of the two arcs.  Does your "between" mean the third point is on the smaller arc?
What if the arcs are the same size?

Comment: See the clarification above.

Comment: @jgyou didn't consider using modular math... can you point me in the direction of an example or outline a solution? Im not that familiar with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've marked **@tp1** answer correct because of the effort he expended in answering it, but I've not gotten around to testing it. It is computationally intensive and the following ended up being a simpler (and probably *faster*) solution which didn't require transforming the angle values into cartesian coordinates.

This *definitely* works in all cases I can think to test.

```
bool is_P3_between_P1_and_P2(double p1, double p2, double p3)
{
  double p1_p2, p1_p3;
  p1_p2 = fmod(p2 - p1 + 360, 360);
  p1_p3 = fmod(p3 - p1 + 360, 360);

  return (p1_p2 <= 180) != (p1_p3 > p1_p2);
}
```

Comment: The limit cases when p3 is equal to p1 or p2 becomes sort of weird, but otherwise looks correct (and probably won't occur with floating point arithmetic). On a side note, why do you add $2$ times $360$ instead of only $1$ time $360$? Assuming all angles are in the range $[0,360)$, angles differences fall within $(-360,360)$ so adding $360$ once should guarantee that the value passed to fmod is positive. If you're sceptical about floating point accuracy, you're probably better off using computational geometry tools imo.

Comment: @N.Bach You are correct! There is no need to multiply by 2. I just tested and it wasn't required. The boundary case is sort of a problem, but as you say will not likely occur or will do so very infrequently (an error I can live with). This routine is used to test if p3 is in the short arc between p1 and p2 (2 positions of a body 24hrs apart) and if so then an interpolation routine is used to determine at what time an occultation took place.

Comment: if there's more than one answer to same question, crosschecking the results will give better confidence that everything works ok.

Comment: Frankly I think you should accept _this_ answer (even though it's your own) so that someone else who has the same question will see this answer first. (The accepted answer is always shown just after the question, above all others.) This is the answer I would want to see if I were implementing this. (In fact it is similar to the way I _have_ implemented this kind of function when I needed it!)

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily solved by "angle between two lines". Form angle between origo-A and origo-B, and another angle between origo-A and origo-P, and you'll get two angles. Now which one is larger will determine whether P is between A and B.

Angle between two lines $(x_1,x_2),(x_3,x_4)$ can be found from:
$$ \cos \alpha = \frac{(x_2-x_1) \cdot (x_4-x_3)}{|x_2-x_1| |x_4-x_3|} $$, which means you'll use $\arccos$ to find the angles. You need to use this twice. Then it's just matter of comparing which angle is larger. Obviously you need to know the position of the point $(x,y) = (r \cos \beta, r \sin \beta)$ and position of origo $O(x,y) = (0,0)$.

So to wrap up, if your input is angles $p1 = 358$, $p2 = 1$, $p3 = .5$, then you'll need the following ($r$ is arbitrary choice $\neq 0$, for example $r=1.0$):
$$ (x_1,y_1) = (r \cos(p1), r \sin(p1)) \\
   (x_2,y_2) = (r \cos(p2), r \sin(p2)) \\
   (x_3,y_3) = (r \cos(p3), r \sin(p3)) \\
   (o_x,o_y) = (0,0)$$,
then the lines are $((x_1,y_1),(o_x,o_y))$ and $((x_2,y_2),(o_x,o_y))$:
 $$ \alpha = \arccos { \frac{((x_1,y_1)-(o_x,o_y))\cdot((x_2,y_2)-(o_x,o_y))} {|(x_1,y_1)-(o_x,o_y)| |(x_2,y_1)-(o_x,o_y)| } }$$
Then the 2nd lines are $((x_3,y_3),(o_x,o_y))$ and $((x_1,y_1),(o_x,o_y))$:
   $$ \beta_1 = \arccos { \frac{((x_3,y_3)-(o_x,o_y))\cdot((x_1,y_1)-(o_x,o_y))}{|((x_3,y_3)-(o_x,o_y))| |((x_1,y_1)-(o_x,o_y))| } } $$
   $$ \beta_2 = \arccos { \frac{((x_3,y_3)-(o_x,o_y))\cdot((x_2,y_2)-(o_x,o_y))}{|((x_3,y_3)-(o_x,o_y))| |((x_2,y_2)-(o_x,o_y))| } } $$
   $$ \beta = max(\beta_1,\beta_2) $$

Then it's just comparision:
  $$\alpha < \beta $$
(note that there's still notational conviniences for $a \cdot b$ and $|a|$ an $a-b$ for dot product and distance of a vector and vector difference:
  $$ (a_x,a_y) \cdot (b_x,b_y) = a_x b_x + a_y b_y \\
   |(a_x,a_y)| = \sqrt{a_x^2+a_y^2} \\
   (a_x,a_y) - (b_x,b_y) = (a_x-b_x, a_y-b_y) $$
)

Comment: Sorry but Im not following this at all. Can you point me in the direction of a more complete explanation of this?

Comment: Thanks for this, this looks promising but I am not clear on what 'x' is in relation to the degree values I provided in the example where p1=358, p2=2 and i need to know if p3 at .5 degrees is between them.

Comment: Thank you for this extensive explanation. I will have to investigate further if it does in fact solve my issue. Some of the notation is a little unclear to me in terms of translating into code. Can I read this: ((x1,y1)−(ox,oy))⋅((x2,y2)−(ox,oy)) to mean this: ((x1-x0) - (y1-y0)) * ((x2-x0) - (y2-y0)) also Im not clear on the correct algebraic interpretation of |a||b|

Comment: the |a||b| is just ordinary multiplication.

Comment: Ok thanks and can the expression I mentioned be re-written the way I did in the last comment? If so I understand the rest and what to do.

Comment: no. you should use only the stuff mentioned in the answer, since its now complete.

Comment: Well sorry then but I don't understand how to implement an expression like ((x1,y1)−(ox,oy))⋅((x2,y2)−(ox,oy)) in c... I'll need to understand how to interpret that or where to do to learn how to interpret it.

Comment: you need two separate concepts: $a \cdot b$ and $ a - b $. Once both are working, then it shouldn't need anything else but use them together. $a-b$ is more difficult since the function needs to return a pair.

Comment: And how does that response help me understand how to implement the expression I just hightlighted? I've asked this question about 3 times now.

Comment: struct P { float x, float y; }; P minus(P p1, P p2) { P res; res.x = p1.x-p2.x; res.y=p1.y-p2.y; return res; } float dot(P p1, P p2) { return p1.x*p2.x+p1.y*p2.y; } float expr(P p1, P o, P p2, P o2) { return dot(minus(p1,o), minus(p2,o2)); }

Comment: Ahh, Now I get it! Ok, thanks for that and I will try implementing this. I will mark this answer correct for now for your efforts.... hopefully it actually works :)

Answer (score 2):

From your description, I assume you have the variables p1 and p2 that represent the location of the two given points on the circle, given as an angle in the range $[0,360)$.

I'll assume that `p1<p2`. If this is not the case, just swap their values.

If `p2-p1<=180`, then the short arc is from p1 to p2, and you want the angle x of your third point to be between them.
If `p2-p1>180`, then the long arc is from p1 to p2, and you want the angle x of your third point to not be between them.

So you can write the condition in short as 

`(p2-p1<=180) == (p1<=x AND x<=p2)`

In longhand form it would be

`((p2-p1<=180) AND (p1<=x AND x<=p2))`

`OR`

`(NOT(p2-p1<=180) AND NOT (p1<=x AND x<=p2))`

Answer (score 1):

You want to know if numbers $a,b,c\in[0,360)$ correspond to angles in anticlockwise order. This is the case if and only if either $a<b<c$ or $b<c<a$ or $a<c<b$.

Comment: I think the last should be $c<a<b$.